# How to make RubyMine align equations neatly?

Tags: rubymine

In RubyMine, I have some code in this form:

```
a = b
cd = e
fgh = i
```

I would like it to auto-format to something like this:

```
a   = b
cd  = e
fgh = i
```

Does anyone know whether this is possible (or I have to keep doing it by hand), and if so how I could set it up? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preference -> Editor -> Code Style -> Ruby -> Other -> **✓Align right parts of assignments or hashes**

Then `Code -> Reformat Code` manually.

[image]

Comment: In the current version of RubyMine (2021.2) you will find this option here: `Preference -> Editor -> Code Style -> Ruby -> Wrapping and Braces -> Assignments and Hashes -> Align right parts`